# JSONP Ajax Call with JQuery causes memory leak

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I already searched a complete day and cannot find the issue why I get such big memory leaks in my phonegap application, which uses a lot of ajax-jsonp requests to the server.

Therefore I broke it down to the simplest example. You can find it [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seb_zill/N9R56/).

The main content of it is:

```
function run(){
   $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://thawing-bayou-7281.herokuapp.com/test.js",
        success: function (res) {
            // some stuff here
            setTimeout(run, 250);
        }
    });
};
run();
```

So this code calls a jsonp api request an endless time every 250ms.

***Please note:*** I know that this is an example you would never implement like that! It's just for detecting the memory leak.

When I run this example the used memory increases rapidly (you can see it best in the Chromes Timeline Tab).
[image]
The number of **DOM Nodes** is increasing as well rapidly. At some point it breaks down (maybe some GC?) but the elements and the needed memory increases rapidly.

Has anyone of you an idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a memory leak, sawtooth type graphs are common in java.  Memory usage ramps up, the garbage collector gets called, and it drops down.  The graph you showed represents just such a situation.

You would have a memory leak if the low points of the graph continually increased, which is not being shown in your graph.

Comment: Java?! Think you mean JavaScript there, buddy! Java does also have garbage collection...